# Access Host between two Subnetworks

Tags: networking, subnet

Can this two hosts ping/access each other without routing?

```
Host A:

172.17.1.1
255.255.255.0
N-ID: 172.17.1.0
BC: 172.17.1.255

Host B:

172.17.1.10
255.255.0.0
N-ID: 172.17.0.0
BC: 172.17.255.255
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both machines think they are on same network, as the subnet mask includes both addresses on both hosts.

Comment: this works when host B is using an /8 mask? Can both hosts access each other or only Host B->A ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. the subnet mask specifies the size of the directly connected network for a host. in other words what addresses are accessible without going via a gateway (router). The subnet mask configured on host B includes A's address (172.17.0.0 - 172.17.255.255) . The subnet mask on host A includes B's address (172.17.1.0 - 172.17.1.255). Both host sees the other hosts address as directly connected. Both host can ping each other. But you should really try to **avoid this configuration** as it is confusing, and will possibly cause problems for you later.